# How to get a transparent background after scrolling down in light box?

Tags: css

I found a code for light box using a simple java script  from [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/). The problem here is the transparent background is not coming when i scroll down the page.Here is my css

```
.black_overlay{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity:.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
   border-radius:10px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

and  what i got is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prabhakardevineni/Jz4Zq/)

please give me some suggesstions

Thanks for reading   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one,

```
.black_overlay {
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity:.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.white_content {
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius:10px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jz4Zq/2/

Comment: Thanks it really works.But i wanna ask you one thing what is the thing that makes it work and how?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `height:100%` which uses the 100% height for the element it is contained in. You will have to adjust the `top` property of the element when scrolling, or setting the height by javascript.